# Powershell script for Coveo Indexing

Tags: coveo, powershell

I am using this Powershell script for Coveo indexing, but I do not see the output after waiting for a long time. I can see that indexing is running in "Coveo indexing manager". But its not completing or giving any messages. Could anyone suggest about this issue?

```
using namespace Sitecore.ContentSearch
$indexes = [ContentSearchManager]::Indexes
foreach($index in $indexes){
   if($index.Name  -match  "Coveo")
   {
    Write-Host "Re-indexing started " $index.Name
    $index.Rebuild([IndexingOptions]::ForcedIndexing);
    Write-Host "Re-indexing Finished" $index.Name 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

When you take a look at signature of **Rebuild** method you will notice that it's `void` which means it doesn't return any value, handle, nothing.

Technically you received what you asked for because you've only asked index to be rebuilded.

---

**Solution**

If you want to track progress in PowerShell you need to modify your code a little bit.

Here is an example how you can rebuild **sitecore_core_index** index and track progress in PowerShell.

```powershell
# get index object
$index = [Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager]::Indexes | ? { $_.Name -eq "sitecore_core_index" }
# invoke index rebuild and get job handle
$job = $index | Initialize-SearchIndex -AsJob

# while job is running display job status with 1 second delay
while ($job.Status.State -eq "Running") {
    $job.Status
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

**Results**

***Script*** - console output
[image]

***Jobs Viewer*** (`https://sc/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx`)
[image]